# how to get index of hyperlinks inside div

Tags: jquery, html, indexing

```
<div class="nav">
   <a href="#item1">item1</a>
   <a href="#item2">item2</a>
   <a href="#item3">item3</a>
</div>
```

I have html structure as above, i want to get index of hyperlinks on click via jquery.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something??

Comment: Funny how 1 answer after minutes spawns 5 other answers within a minute.

Comment: I had tried by,
$(".nav a").size(); and $(".nav a").length();
but not worked,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
var index = $("a").index(this);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DVxLT/)**

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".nav a").click(function () {
    console.log( $(this).index() );
});
```

This will give you the index of the hyperlink.

For jQuery 1.7+, you can use `on`, you can see this like a delegate added to the hyperlinks.

```
$(".nav").on("click", "a", function() {
    console.log( $(this).index() );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

```
$('.nav a').on('click', function() {
    console.log($(this).index());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the position of the passed element relative to the original collection.

```
$(function(){
   $(".nav > a").click(function (event) {
      console.log( "Clicked link index::"+ $(this).index() );
     event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```